# How to propagete principal when calling the same EJB from JAX-RS and EJB Sheduler / CXF, OpenEJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs

I have an BusinessEJB which is creating some database entities and it has to know currently logged principal.
This EJB may be called via REST ( via another @Path annotated proxy EJB) as also out from JAX-RS context - straight from other EJBs - even EJB Sheduler;

The question is how to use one common solution to propagate principal to this EJB - during JAX-RS calls I may get principal from token ( I tried to setSecurityContext but it propagates only to @Path annotated class - not to final EJB) and how to set a "system" principal for calls from EJB timer calls.
I've used some ThreadLocal solutions but I'm sure there must be some proper way..

```
@Stateless
class BusinessEJB 
{   
    public void createRecord() { 
        ...
        currentUser = ?????????
        newEntity.setCreatetBy( currentUser.. );        

    } 
}


@Path("/api")
class RestEJB {
    @EJB
    BusinessEJB businessEJB;

    public void createRecord() { 
         businessEJB.createRecord();   
    } 
}

class SchedulerEJB
{ 
    @EJB
    BusinessEJB businessEJB;

    @Shedule
    private void sheduleFn() {
        // here we should set some system user context ??? 
        businessEJB.createRecord();
   } 
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `SessionContext#getCallerPrincipal()`? [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getCallerPrincipal%28%29) and [example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bncaa/index.html)